# jqgrid - filter/search always gives me only "contains" operator for a option

Tags: search, jqgrid, operators

I am using jQgrid - and it is great!

I have one problem.
(Oleg are you still around?)
In the search/filter form (were you can choose the coulmn you want to filter and the operation you want do to), the only things that comes up is the "contain" operator.

My colModel looks like this:

```
var columnModel = [{ name: 'ID', index: 'ID', sortable: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn','bw']}},
{ name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', sortable: true},
{ name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', sortable: true }
];
```

But it only gives me the contains operator.

The full grid is like this:

```
myGrid.jqGrid({
    url: './ViewNQueryData.asmx/ViewNQueryData',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    postData: {userID:currentUserId, sphereID:currentSphereId},
    ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
    serializeGridData: function (postData)
    {
        if (postData.filters === undefined) postData.filters = null;
        return JSON.stringify(postData);
    },
    jsonReader: {
        root: function (obj) { return obj.d.rows; },
        page: function (obj) { return obj.d.page; },
        total: function (obj) { return obj.d.total; },
        records: function (obj) { return obj.d.records; }
    },
    colModel: columnModel,
    colNames: columnNames,
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 300],
    sortable: true,
    pager: "#ViewNQueryPager",
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    height: 250,
    shrinkToFit: true, //If using frozen coulmns change to false.

    gridComplete: function ()
    {
        $('#totalRecordsFound').html(myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records') + " Customers");
    },
    loadError: function ()
    {
        alert("Error fetching data");
    }
}).jqGrid('navGrid', '#ViewNQueryPager',
                { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: true, view: true }, //option
                {}, // use default settings for edit
                {}, // use default settings for add
                {}, // delete instead that del:false we need this
                {multipleSearch: true, multipleGroup: true, showQuery: true, onSearch: function (response) { showQueryDetails(); } },
                { height: 250, jqModal: false, closeOnEscape: true} // view options
                );
```

Can any one help me with this???

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors on the page? I was unable to reproduce the behavior you are seeing: http://jsfiddle.net/Rp6Gc/

Comment: Thank you very much! But i just found the problem, i had something else on the page the made that happen.... how can i close this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!
I had a snippet of code on my page that was doing this....